# How to pipe the stdout of a command, depending on the result of the exit code

Tags: bash, control-flow

Expanding from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed), we have a use case where we want to pipe the stdout of a command depending on whether that command succeeded or failed.

We start with a basic pipe

```
command | grep -P "foo"
```

However we notice that sometimes `command` does not output anything to stdout, but does have an exit code of `0`. We want to ignore this case and only apply the `grep` when the exit code is `1`

For a working example, we could implement a command like this:

```bsh
OUTPUT=$(command) # exit code is 0 or 1
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
  return $RESULT; # if the exit code is 0 then we simply pass it forward
else
  grep -P "foo" <<< $OUTPUT; # otherwise check if the stdout contains "foo"
fi
```

but this has a number of disadvantages, namely that you have to write a script, meaning you can't just execute it in the console.
It also seems somewhat amateurish.

For a more concise syntax, I'm imagining a fictional ternary operator which pipes if the exit code is `1`, otherwise it passes the exit code forwards.

```bsh
command |?1 grep -P "foo" : $?
```

Is there a series of operators and utils that will achieve this result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Commands in a pipeline run concurrently, that's the whole point of pipes, and inter-process communication mechanism.

In:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

`cmd1` and `cmd2` are started at the same time, `cmd2` processes the data that `cmd1` writes as it comes.

If you wanted `cmd2` to be started only if `cmd1` had failed, you'd have to start `cmd2` after `cmd1` has finished and reported its exit status, so you couldn't use a pipe, you'd have to use a temporary file that holds all the data the `cmd1` has produced:

```
 cmd1 > file || cmd2 < file; rm -f file
```

Or store in memory like in your example but that has a number of other issues (like `$(...)` removing all trailing newline characters, and most shells can't cope with NUL bytes in there, not to mention the scaling issues for large outputs).

On Linux and with shells like `zsh` or `bash` that store here-documents and here-strings in temporary files, you could do:

```
{ cmd1 > /dev/fd/3 || cmd2 <&3 3<&-; } 3<<< ignored
```

To let the shell deal with the temp file creation and clean-up.

bash version 5 now removes write permissions to the temp file after creating it, so the above wouldn't work, you'll need to work around it by restoring the write permission first:

```
{ chmod u+w /dev/fd/3
  cmd1 > /dev/fd/3 || cmd2 <&3 3<&-; } 3<<< ignored
```

Manually, POSIXly:

```
tmpfile=$(
  echo 'mkstemp(template)' |
    m4 -D template="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/XXXXXX"
) && [ -n "$tmpfile" ] && (
  rm -f -- "$tmpfile" || exit
  cmd1 >&3 3>&- 4<&- ||
    cmd2 <&4 4<&- 3>&-) 3> "$tmpfile" 4< "$tmpfile"
```

Some systems have a non-standard `mktemp` command (though with an interface that varies between systems) that makes the tempfile creation a bit easier (`tmpfile=$(mktemp)` should be enough with most implementation, though some would not create the file so you may need to adjust the `umask`). The `[ -n "$tmpfile" ]` should not be necessary with compliant `m4` implementations, but GNU `m4` at least is not compliant in that it doesn't return a non-zero exit status when the `mkstemp()` call fails.

Also note that there's nothing stopping you running any code in the *console*. Your *"script"* can be entered just the same at the prompt of an interactive shell (except for the `return` part that assumes the code is in a function), though you can simplify it to:

```
output=$(cmd) || grep foo <<< "$output"
```

Comment: Excellent. Both `cmd1 > file || cmd2 < file` and `output=$(cmd) || grep foo <<< "$output"` achieve the results in full. With the former syntax I have to later clean up by removing the file, but this is not a big deal and provides quite a few options. Thanks.

Comment: See also [chronic](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/moreutils/chronic.1.en.html) from moreutils which addresses a similar situation

Comment: use `(f=\`mktemp\`; exec 3>$f 4<$f; rm $f; cmd1 >&3 || cmd2 <&4)` if you don't want to have to clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Note: Since the question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I assume you can use bash features.

Given your example code, it seems what you want to do is:

- Use the command's exit status if it's 0,
- Use `grep`'s exit status otherwise.

Running `grep` on an empty pipeline doesn't cost you anything, so one option would be to pipe it anyway, and check the command's exit status, which you can get using the `PIPESTATUS` array in bash:

```
$ (echo foo; exit 1) | grep foo
foo
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1 0
```

Here, the subshell exited with 1, grep exited with 0.

So you could do something like:

```
(command | grep -P "foo"; exit "$((PIPESTATUS[0] ? $? : 0))")
```

The expression could be simplified, but you get the idea.

---

There's also the option to simply fake output:

```
(command && echo foo) | grep -P foo
```

Where `echo foo` will run only if the command succeeded, making the grep succeed too.