# Check if the command with input from echo succeeded

Tags: bash

It is quite [straightforward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed/22728#22728) to check if a single command returned exit code 0. However, I'm not sure what to do if I use echo with a command. For example, in this case, program I want to test definitely returns non-zero exit code, but it looks like bash looks at echo's exit code instead, which is 0:

```
    if echo "something" > exit 42; then
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "NOT OK"
    fi
```

It makes impossible to check if a program which requires interactive input returned non-zero exit code. How can I fix that and get the exit code of the program I'm echoing something to?

Comment: _program I want to test definitely returns non-zero exit code_ - but what program are you testing here?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk here I've added exit just to show that it returns bad exit code and still prints "OK". Originally, it looked like `if echo "something" > ./mybinary; then`

Comment: You're not exiting here but redirecting output of echo to a file called `exit`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk oh, I see, bash does exit as it should, the problem was that I passed the input incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Should I remove the question, or should I post that as an answer?

Comment: It's up to you, it's your question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that bash does exit just fine. The problem was that
`if echo "something" > exit 42; then` just printed "something" to file called exit instead of running exit, so the return code was actually 0. To fix that, you should use "|". `if echo "something" | exit 42; then` works as expected.

Comment: Actually, it should have printed `something 42` to the file called `exit`. The position of a simple redirect doesn't usually matter

Comment: `echo "something" | exit 42` is bad code, because `exit` doesn't expect anything on _stdin_, and the output from `echo` is lost. The correct construct would simply be two commands: `echo 'something'; exit 42`. However, I'm still not at all sure what you're trying to achieve with your original piece of code