tar returning different exit code when wrapped inside if statement
I have a script which creates a tar archive filtered through xz. I have wrapped the tar command inside an if statement so the script can take different actions depending on whether the archive was created successfully or not:
if [[ $(XZ_OPT=-9eT2 tar -Jcf $BackupPath $BackupArchive) == 0 ]];
then

   # Success

else

   # Failed

fi

When executed as above, tar's exit code is 1. But if I run the same command interactively and not inside an if statement:
mongotron@server:~$ XZ_OPT=-9eT2 tar -Jcf $BackupPath $BackupArchive && echo $?
0

...the exit code is 0, as I would expect.
Any help would be appreciated.

You're actually checking the output, not the exit status. You should use https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22728/70524 for implicitly checking zero vs non-zero exit status, or something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22727/70524 for checking specific exit status values

The exit code of your command in the command substitution in the if statement might be zero, but its output, which is what you use in the comparison, is not the string 0.
To use the exit status of a command with if, don't use the square brackets (nor command substitution):
if tar ...; then
    echo ok
else
    echo not ok
fi

This would cause the shell to take the first branch if the exit status of the tar command was zero, and the else branch if it was something non-zero.
Also remember to quote your variable expansion:
if XZ_OPT=-9eT2 tar -c -J -f "$BackupPath" "$BackupArchive"
then
    echo ok
else
    echo not ok
fi

